# Accessing gmail account from a C# windows service application

Tags: gmail-api

I'm writing a windows service application which needs to monitor one or more GMAIL inboxes for incoming emails.  It downloads new emails and parses and extact the information.  I believe using POP/IMAP/SMTP client api is the best way to solve this problem.  Am I correct in my assumption?  OAUTH authorization doesn't fit in this kind of scenario because there no user sititng to enter there credentials.

Comment: Can my scenario be addressed using "server to server interaction" option (using service accounts)?

Comment: Are you just going to do this for your own accounts?

Comment: It coudl be any gmail for which my application has user name/pwd.

Comment: I see. You could use IMAP, but if you can redirect your users to google and get their `refresh_token` and `access_token`, you could use the Gmail api which is a lot nicer to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  So, if I were to do the approach you suggested, I will first need some Network Admin to use a desktop application to retrieve "tokens" for each account they want my windows service to access.  They would then feed those tokens to my windows service application.  The windows service app will then use that to call the Gmail apis.

Comment: That's right. You would only need to set up two publicly accessible routes on your server; one that will redirect the user to Google with your app's `client secret` and `client id`. If they accept, Google will redirect the user to your second route that will get a `code` you can exchange for a `refresh_token` and `access_token`. After that, you are ready to go.